# Subscript is invalid because list is empty: In Trigger

Tags: trigger, controller, singleemailmessage

I implemented one trigger in Parent object.I am getting the following error while creating child record.

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger Testorg caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: Testorg : execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, Subscript is invalid because list is
>   empty: []: Trigger.Testorg:

**Code:**

```
String whereCond = ' Where (test_Min__c <='+listmoney +'AND test_Max__c >='+listmoney +
                     ') AND (Minemp__c <='+mmtotal +
                     'AND Maxemp__c >='+mmtotal+') AND'; 
String finalQuery = 'SELECT Id,Name,Email__c FROM Property__c '+ 
                     whereCond +'(Status__c INCLUDES (\'test1\') OR
                                  Status__c INCLUDES (\'test2\'))' + 'LIMIT 3';
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: i am getting error based on this condition:

String whereCond = ' Where (test_Min__c <='+listmoney +'AND test_Max__c >='+listmoney +') AND (Minemp__c <='+mmtotal +'AND Maxemp__c >='+mmtotal+') AND';  

 String finalQuery = 'SELECT Id,Name,Email__c FROM Property__c '+ whereCond  +'(Status__c INCLUDES (\'test1\') OR Status__c INCLUDES (\'test2\'))' + 'LIMIT 3';

Comment: I don't think the error comes from this condition. It seems that you use the SendEmail class in a trigger. Please copy the code in your question.